# SharePoint version storage

Tags: sharepoint-server, configuration, topology

Will SharePoint store each version as a whole physical copy or just the delta difference in disk? This information is required for sizing considerations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the SharePoint version.

If you are using SharePoint 2010 or older then SharePoint stores a copy of a document every time a new version is created. I.e. a document of 10MB with 10 versions will be 100MB in storage.

But if you are using SharePoint 2013 or 2016 then you can take advantage of [shredded storage](http://www.jeremythake.com/2012/12/the-truth-behind-shredded-storage-in-sharepoint-2013/), which mean every time you create a new version it stores only a delta.

Comment: As mentioned by Jeremy Thake, the new Shredded Storage technology only works with the Office XML formats. PDF documents and other non-Office formats will still store a full copy for each version.